# The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory is not working from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy a gradle web project using tomcat in eclipse and when I am trying to access the application it throws me an exception as follows:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [36] in the generated java file: [......plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina...\org\apache\jsp\error_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)

The same application I am able to deploy manually in the tomcat server with out using eclipse then it is working perfectly.

Please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

While deploying the application into server using eclipse it is adding some dependencies which are conflicted to dependencies added using gradle, after removing the conflicted jars the solved the issue.

the generated war only have the jars which are configured in the gradle so that is working when we deploy it manually on the server.